# Limit hover to the text width

Tags: html, css, hover

I have these text which I added `hover` to them, But I want the border (`border: 2px solid grey`) to be limited around the text and not the entire box, how is it possible?

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reshadgp/vp9v5be8/)**

```css
.eachTitle {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: "riesling";
  color: #80FF00;
}

.eachTitle:hover {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="eachTitle" id="menu">Our Menu</div>
<div class="eachTitle" id="gallery" style="margin-left: 80px;">Gallery</div>
<div class="eachTitle" id="map" style="margin-left: 160px;">Where are we?</div>
<div class="eachTitle" id="about" style="margin-left: 240px;">About us</div>
```

Comment: you need to create child element and set hover style for that. Here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/6oy5s7kc/

Comment: @VijayBaskaran Thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.eachTitle {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: "riesling";
  color: #80FF00;
}

.hoverspan:hover {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="eachTitle" id="menu"><span class="hoverspan">Our Menu</span></div>
<div class="eachTitle" id="gallery" style="margin-left: 80px;"><span class="hoverspan">Gallery</span></div>
<div class="eachTitle" id="map" style="margin-left: 160px;"><span class="hoverspan">Where are we?</span></div>
<div class="eachTitle" id="about" style="margin-left: 240px;"><span class="hoverspan">About us</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap each element in `span` and apply border to that element.

```css
.eachTitle {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: "riesling";
  color: #80FF00;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.eachTitle span {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}
.eachTitle:hover span {
  border-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="eachTitle" id="menu"><span>Our Menu</span>
</div>
<div class="eachTitle" id="gallery" style="margin-left: 80px;"><span>Gallery</span>
</div>
<div class="eachTitle" id="map" style="margin-left: 160px;"><span>Where are we?</span>
</div>
<div class="eachTitle" id="about" style="margin-left: 240px;"><span>About us</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this one I prefer the most.

Comment: just one problem is that now the whole line is clickable

Comment: you mean I add an style to span tag and put  cursor: pointer; in it?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div  id="menu"><span class="eachTitle">Our Menu</span></div>
```

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4dhhe8kt/2/)